# Type Mismatch error on string creation VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue that I can't quite figure out through google searching.  I'm constructing a string based on cell content within a workbook and values from a variant array and getting a type mismatch error when the code reaches the argument where I construct the string.  Code below.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
    Dim taskAssignments As String
        taskAssignments = ws.[getTaskAssignment] & var(i, 1) & ws.[getTaskAssignment2]
```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to give you a definitive answer. Exactly what is `getTaskAssignment`/`getTaskAssignment2` (seriously? how about *meaningful names*?) and what's its value?

Comment: Try putting each of the 3 into the taskAssignments string one at a time to see *which* one is causing the issue?

Comment: Try it as `ws.Range("getTaskAssignment")` in **both** places.

Comment: if `getTaskAssignment` and `getTaskAssignment2` are the names of two _named ranges_ local to the same worksheet to which `ws` is a valid object reference, then your code is likely to fail in the `var(i, 1)` part -> wrap it in a `Cstr()` call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping each value in `CStr()` to explicitly convert the values to a `String`:

```
taskAssignments = CStr(ws.[getTaskAssignment]) & cstr(var(i, 1)) & cstr(ws.[getTaskAssignment2])
```

Comment: If the cell contains an error, this will blow up all the same.

Comment: Also try using .Value at the end of every range. such as ws.[getTaskAssignment].Value ... you can combine this with Cstr() if needed.

Comment: this worked - thanks.  the cell didn't contain an error, I've already vetted that.  I'll accept the answer in a few.